# date time mysql for comments section

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I have a question regarding Date and Time for MYSQL.  Basically I started building a comments section for a web project I have going on.  I was building out the DB table and wanted to know how the DB stores the date and time.

For instance if I am in LA and the time is 7:00 PM will it store the comment at 7PM and say that I am from New York obviously and I see the comment its 10 PM so what time will I see the 7PM that wouldnt really make sense. I am wondering how you solve this problem and differentiate between different time-zones.

I am imagining that the server has its own time zone associated with it so all time is delineated from that which would make things a whole lot easier. But is it right that a person sees their time from a post as 10PM when it was made at 7PM.  This is all very confusing to me.  Any information on how to regularly deal with this issue or if I have one at all will be greatly appreciated. I am building my site using PHP and Codeigniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally just store the times in the database under an INT ( 11 ) and use the native PHP time() function to get the time, and then you can convert this into a nicer format of a date using some of the PHP functions http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php you can get the year, month, day, hour, minute, etc.

You then can easily just add or subtract the # of hours (3600 seconds in an hour) depending on the time zone.  May be an easier way to do this, but this is how I am currently doing it :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Ask the user their timezone and adjust times accordingly.
2. Show the timezone with the date ("9pm ET")
3. Do what StackOverflow does, and say "2 mins ago".